# Navigation bar is not visible at runtime in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad

I have added Navigation Controller to the ViewController and then I add title to my navigation item, it is showing that title in xcode but when i run the program the title is not visible. I have tried this code within viewDidLoad method

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"My Title"];
```

but it is also not working, Even if i put navigation bar button then also it is not visible. Somebody please help me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You add a viewController to the navigationController not the other way around.

Comment: show me your code for Navigation Controller initialization

Comment: when i link one view controller with another using a button selecting push option then the navigation bar is visible but with modal option it appears once but when i switch back to that view then it does not appears

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"My Title"];
```

Use:

```
self.title=@"your text here";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.title = @"add title here";
```